# Rolling multiple rows into a one row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using google sheets/excel to combine all the unique locations associated with unique role with a single email.

Example

[image]

Outcome

[image]

I just can't think of a way to start this. I thought maybe I can do something like on Column D

`=if(a2=a1,concatenate(c1, ", ", 2))` the clean that out on Column E etc but don't think it'll work well with a file that has over 10,000 rows.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: One could also try `=LET(X,UNIQUE(A2:B14),VSTACK(A1:C1,HSTACK(X,BYROW(X,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(C2:C14,A2:A14&"|"&B2:B14=TEXTJOIN("|",,a))))))))` but it would require access to the BETA-channel.

Comment: I don't have access to VSTACK and HSTACK yet, but that's a need way to include headers.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Office 365, I suggest:

- Create a table from your original data (Home=>Format as table)

```
F1: Email       G1: Role     H1: Location

F2:  =UNIQUE(INDEX(emails,SEQUENCE(ROWS(emails)),{1,2}))

G2:  =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(emails[Location],((F2=emails[Email])*(G2=emails[Role]))))
```

Select G2 and fill down as far as needed.

[image]

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- The algorithm Groups by Email and Role; and then returns the
  Locations as a concatenated list

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="emails"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Email", type text}, {"Role", type text}, {"Location", type text}}),
    group = Table.Group(#"Changed Type",{"Email","Role"},{
        {"Locations", each Text.Combine([Location],", "), type text}
    })
in
    group
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted like you have it, you can do this. In Column D:

```
=IF(B2 <> B3, B2, "")
```

Then set E2 = C2, and in E3 do:

```
=IF(B3 <> B2, C3, CONCATENATE(E2, ",", C3))
```

After dragging these down you can filter on Column D not blank and get your end result.

This same thing is more easily accomplished with Data > Outline > Subtotal on the range when doing straight math instead of concatenation, but that's not your requirement here.